# java.util.SimpleTimezone what is startMode and endMode?

Tags: java

I'm trying out the SimpleTimeZone of Java and I want to understand the values that it generates when I create a new SimpleTimeZone object. Firstly, here's my code and the output

```
import java.util.*;

public class SimpleTimeZoneDemo {
    public static void main( String args[] ){
    // create simple time zone object
    SimpleTimeZone stobj = new SimpleTimeZone(820,"GMT");

    // checking initial value     
    System.out.println("Initial value: " + stobj);

    // setting start rule   
    stobj.setStartRule( Calendar.MAY, 2, 3600000);   

    // checking the new value      
    System.out.println("Final value : " + stobj);
}
```

The output it generates is

```
Initial value: java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=GMT,offset=820,dstSavings=3600000,
useDaylight=false,startYear=0,startMode=0,startMonth=0,startDay=0,
startDayOfWeek=0,startTime=0,startTimeMode=0,endMode=0,endMonth=0,endDay=0,
endDayOfWeek=0,endTime=0,endTimeMode=0]

Final value : java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=GMT,offset=820,dstSavings=3600000,
useDaylight=false,startYear=0,startMode=1,startMonth=4,startDay=2,
startDayOfWeek=0,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=0,
endMonth=0,endDay=0,endDayOfWeek=0,endTime=0,endTimeMode=0]
```

What is `startMode` and `endMode`? Why did `startMode` changed from 0 to 1? I'm trying to figure it out and it seems related to day light savings time?

Comment: Why does the public toString() method return a string that mentions undocumented & inaccessible fields?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou That's the real question isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startMode` and `endMode` are internal field. You can't access them in the public API.

However, they are documented if take a look inside the source code:

For `startMode`:

> Variables specifying the mode of the start rule.  Takes the following values:
>
> - `DOM_MODE`: Exact day of week; e.g., March 1.
> - `DOW_IN_MONTH_MODE`: Day of week in month; e.g., last Sunday in March.
> - `DOW_GE_DOM_MODE`: Day of week after day of month; e.g., Sunday on or after March 15.
> - `DOW_LE_DOM_MODE`: Day of week before day of month; e.g., Sunday on or before March 15.
>
> The setting of this field affects the interpretation of the `startDay` field.
>
> If `useDaylight` is false, this value is ignored.

For `endMode`:

> Variables specifying the mode of the end rule.  Takes the following values:
>
> - `DOM_MODE`: Exact day of week; e.g., March 1.
> - `DOW_IN_MONTH_MODE`: Day of week in month; e.g., last Sunday in March.
> - `DOW_GE_DOM_MODE`: Day of week after day of month; e.g., Sunday on or after March 15.
> - `DOW_LE_DOM_MODE`: Day of week before day of month; e.g., Sunday on or before March 15.
>
> The setting of this field affects the interpretation of the `endDay` field.
>
> If `useDaylight` is false, this value is ignored.

In your code, the `startMode` is 0 in the first case because it isn't initialized so the `int` takes its default value. It changes to 1 because you set a start rule to a specific day, hence the mode becomes `DOM_MODE = 1`. Note that the `endMode` stayed at 0 because no end rule was set.